# Fix logjam vulnerability in courier

Tags: ssl, courier, vulnerabilities, logjam

The site [weakdh.org](https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html) explains how to fix postfix against the weak Diffie-Hellman attack called "logjam".

But don't I have to fix courier too? Or do I have to migrate to dovecot to be logjam-safe?

Comment: Already [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89773/how-to-check-if-a-server-is-not-vulnerable-to-logjam) is a good guide for checking a generic service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this blog post](http://stefanchrist.eu/blog/2015_05_23/Wrong%20again%20-%20Logjam.xhtml) that explains it quite well.

To speed this up, first check, if you already have good parameters in `/etc/ssl/certs/dhparams.pem` check with

```
openssl dhparam -text -noout -in /etc/ssl/certs/dhparams.pem
```

if so copy them into `/etc/courier/dhparams.pem` with

```
cp -a /etc/ssl/certs/dhparams.pem /etc/courier/dhparams.pem
```

otherwise generate with

```
openssl dhparam -out /etc/courier/dhparams.pem 4096
```

[Courrier version 4.15 removes the TLS_DHCERTFILE parameter](http://www.courier-mta.org/imap/INSTALL.html) from imap, and pop3d configuration files. DH parameters, and DH parameters only, get read from the new TLS_DHPARAMS file (and the other functionaly of TLS_DHCERTFILE, for DSA certificates, is merged into TLS_CERTFILE). After upgrading, run the mkdhparams script to create a new TLS_DHPARAMS file.

So check your installed version with

```
 apt-cache show courier-imap-ssl|grep Version
```

If you have at least Version 4.15, now edit `/etc/courier/imapd-ssl` and set

```
TLS_DHPARAMS=/etc/courier/dhparams.pem
```

restart courier-imap-ssl:

```
/etc/init.d/courier-imap-ssl restart
```

check the connection with openssl version 1.0.2a.

```
openssl s_client -host <yourhost.org> -port 993
```

Answer (score 0):

When using courier, you need to make sure that Diffie-Hellman parameters in `/etc/courier/dhparams.pem` are generated with more than the default 768 bit. I guess 2048 or 4096 bit should do.

Instead of using `mkdhparams` to generate `dhparams.pem` (with just 768 bit by default!) you could do it that way:

```
openssl dhparam -out /etc/courier/dhparams.pem 2048

service courier-mta-ssl restart
```

Here's some info (in German) and some further reading about how to [mitigate the Logjam-attack on Courier-MTA.](http://www.slicewise.net/debian/courier-mta-logjam-attacke-umgehen/)

Comment: Unlike the Postfix daemon the Courier POP3 and IMAP daemons require the certificate and key to have been combined into a single file. `courier` uses `TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/courier/imapd.pem` in their settings in `/etc/courier/imapd-ssl` so there has to be done some more i guess. (see http://blog.mekk.com/2010/06/startssl-certificate-free-exim-courier.html )